# Will Alphanumeric contain _ and space?

Tags: testing

If a field is defined as alphanumeric, are spaces and underscores (_) allowed?

I hope they are not.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Please provide more information and meaningful text. What technology/language/framework are you talking about? Or are you asking about the general meaning of *alphanumeric* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric)?

Comment: How is the tag [testing] related to your question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Alphanumeric characters by definition only comprise the letters A to Z and the digits 0 to 9. Spaces and underscores are usually considered punctuation characters, so no, they shouldn't be allowed.

If a field specifically says "alphanumeric characters, space and underscore", then they're included. Otherwise in most cases you generally assume they're not.

Comment: Although in almost every software system I've worked on, underscores are the "notable exception" They can often be used when all other symbols and punctuation are disallowed.

Comment: At least according to Wikipedia, in Perl, the underscore is also considered alphanumeric. Also noteworthy might be the `\w` character class, which contains letters, number and the underscore.

Answer (score 5):

I came here wondering why `\w` in regex includes underscore, I had assumed `\w` meant alphanumeric `[A-Za-z0-9]` but that is not the case in regex.

In most regex engines `\w` is a shortform for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.
However in the case of regex python, besides including underscore, `\w` also includes letters with diacritics, letters from other scripts, etc. Such as the German letter "ö" in "schön".

So now I've learned to use the longform `[A-Za-z0-9]` if I wanted to be specifically alphanumeric in regex.

Comment: I just did test with "schön" at https://regexr.com/787bk and it didn't include diacritics mark

Comment: @AhsaanYousuf Different regex engine has different rules, the link you provided is using a Javascript regex engine (see top right of website), also it has no option to choose a Python regex engine. Here's one [regex101.com/r/u6EToP/1](https://regex101.com/r/u6EToP/1)

Answer (score 2):

Alphanumeric characters are A to Z, a to z and 0 to 9