# How to include spaces while using nameValidator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

To validate the names i have used name Validator in node.js

```
var validate = require('mongoose-validator');
var nameValidator = [
    validate({
        validator: 'isLength',
        arguments: [3, 25],
        message: 'Name should be between {ARGS[0]} and {ARGS[1]} characters'
    }),
    validate({
        validator: 'isAlphanumeric',
        passIfEmpty: true,
        message: 'Name should contain alpha-numeric characters only'
    })
];
```

So when I use the nameValidator for a particular field i can't include white spaces in between them.
Eg. name: Jacob David
I'm getting validation error for the field name

Comment: as you are validation as `isAlphanumeric` , know that in Alpha numeric system, space is not allowed.
see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509262/will-alphanumeric-contain-and-space

Comment: I get that, so is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: i think, name alwys be strings only, you can do `isString` if you need, where space is allowed

Comment: is there validation where only alphabets are taken